# Is there a way to connect with EWS without user credentials if I'm not using Office 365?

Tags: exchangewebservices, php-ews

Original [jamesiarmes/php-ews](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) offers authentication only by username / password. [Fork by Garethp](https://github.com/garethp/php-ews) has some OAuth function but it requires Office365 and registering application in Azure. Is there any possibility to connect to Outlook by web browser just relying on user logged to Windows System? I know how to read which user is logged using kerberos, but don't know if it's right tool to make it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way with either of those tools. I looked in to trying to use Network Authentication as method of Auth, since my fork uses NTLM any way, but I couldn't find any resources on passing the NTLM Authentication over SOAP calls. That being said, if you can find some examples, I'd be happy to build it in as a method of authentication for you

Comment: Is there a way to connect with a (single time exported) token?
I try to connect to an on premise exchange which is behind/authenticated by a Netscaler. From the internal network the authentication works with NTLM (I guess). From external you get redirected to the Netscaler web interface with a token authentication. Do you know a way to export this token/session to make a cron script?

Comment: Sorry, I don't, no. But if you can find some documentation on how to do what you want on the Exchange Web Services SOAP API documentation site, I could help you from there

Answer (score -1):

In the EWS service object, you can select the flag to use default credentials, meaning whatever user context the code is running under.  Would that help?